# PHP foreach Loop Element Index

Tags: php, foreach, nodelist

I have an XPath query that gets Genres of a movie.

```
$genreXpath = $xml_data->xpath("//category");
```

I get the attributes from $genreXpath like this

```
$genreName=array();
$genresID=array();
$i=0;

foreach($genreXpath as $node) {
    $genre = $node->attributes();
    $genreName[$i] = $node["name"];
    $genresID[$i] = $node["id"];    

        $i++;
}
```

I'm going to be writing these values to a Db hence the two different arrays.
This code works but I know there has to be a better way of doing this be it with a 2 d array, not using a $i counter or something more obvious that I haven't figured out....any pointers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($genreXpath as $i=>$node) {  //note $i is your index of the current $node
    $genre = $node->attributes();
    $genreName[$i] = $node["name"];
    $genresID[$i] = $node["id"];    
}
```

It auto increments and you do not need to declare it above.

Comment: You might want to remove `$i++`

Comment: hah, did about 10 seconds before your comment showed up.  thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was doing it the other way $node->$i, I'll get there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach($genreXpath as $key => $node) {`

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to a multidimensional you could do:

```
$genres = array();
foreach($genreXpath as $node) {
    $genre = $node->attributes();
    $genres[] = array($node["name"], $node["id"]);
}
```

Comment: how would that work when I make the SQL insert statement....A bit off topic but while we are at it :)

Comment: @user644347 - I would use an implode. Join the values, and join the "lines".